# Uniquely grouping objects

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I'm creating groups of objects and I'm not really interested in creating a relational database. Basically i am creating a program to group movies for a party and each movie is rated on a 1-5 rating, now no two movies can be at the same party but every party must have at least one 5 star rating movie.

I have knocked out the first part that no two movies can be at the same party by creating unique group IDs using nanotime, however i cannot figure out how to create the second part by grouping the groups with the ratings. I would appreciate some high level problem solving, but please no code, I would prefer to program it myself, thanks for your help. :D

(if it helps i am using java)

Comment: Your question needs more context.  Do you want to write a validation routine that takes a proposed set and tells you whether it fulfils the criteria?  Or something else?  Please be more specific!

Comment: Sorry i see the error in my writing, yes so i would like to create a system to group the movies for parties, because i am going to be renting them out to people. Each movie has the 5 star rating as previously stated but i would like everyone to get at least one 5 star rated movie for their party. I have created a gui so i can generate the party groups multiple times, its really just a sorting method. As for specific code, the long value that stores previous groupings is an arraylist, the ratings are ints and the objects are simply being grouped in regular lists. Thank you for your interest. :D

Comment: @user: So you're looking for a way to randomly generate groups that fulfil the criteria?

Comment: Yes, and each time the groups must be unique, eventually of course you will need to reset the history for the groups. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: what exactly do you mean with this unique criteria? one "customer" should not get a film that he/she already got?

Comment: Well we are giving them groups of films, so the uniqueness of each group is that two movies cannot ever be put in the same group for a party. (Its for a family buisness, I'm not really sure why my mother has asked to do this, but you know, you don't question. ;P )

Comment: I found a problem quite similar to what im trying to do called the knapsack problem via the similar questions on the side. ---->

Comment: I don't understand. If you can't have two movies in the same group, each group must only contain one movie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution would be to group all the movies into a list, sorted by rating descending (thus ensuring that all 5-star movies are at the start). You then iterate over that list, allocating a movie to each party (provided you have more 5-star movies than parties, this will satisfy the condition that all parties need one 5-star movie). You can loop this until all movies have been allocated or until each party has enough movies, whichever comes first.